# Setting responses(answers) in wit.ai

Tags: nlp, wit-ai

I am trying to make an automated chatbot using wit.ai

Till now I have learned that we can add intent and entity so chatbot can better understand the question.

I have a dataset of questions and answers.

1) If there is any way by which I can set answers corresponding to a question(or similar questions) in wit, and how do we set these answers?

for example :

if a user asks:
  what is a phone?
  then our bot should reply the answer which is set by us.

2) if there is any other platform where we can add our dataset of questions and answers to make a chatbot?

Answer (score 2):

1) No, you can't! Since `wit.ai` is working based on *intent classification* and *entity extraction*. You can just learn wit bot to detect intent of a query (for example intent can be *restaurant search*, or *greeting*). Then you can return any desired answers in your side.

2) Almost all platforms are based on intent and entity. You should got for QA bots, like [DeepQA](https://github.com/Conchylicultor/DeepQA).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Quinto](https://quinto.ai/)

You can create question-answer formats there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google dialogflow for this one, https://dialogflow.com/